# Security through different programming language

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp-classic

There is any way to check the login status through different programming language?
Right now I'm using three session (same name) that starts at the same time after the login process, using ajax.

Right now, the **login.html** form is processed on three files: **login.aspx**, **login.asp** and **login.php** but it's seems too slow and weird. I'm combining three different services from the same company into one, after re-building the users and others common tables in mysql, everything seems to work fine, but I'm really scared about security bugs.

Just to let you you know, I have to check the login session status before any ajax callback, so if the user is working on an ASP page calling PHP through Ajax, may be that the session is still active on the ASP, but expired on the php file.

Any valid method to check all in one time? I can also accept a cookie solution but how to make it readable between php, asp and .net?

Comment: why not make all to redirect to one page ? (login.aspx)

Comment: Definitely an XY problem - have all your authentication go through one central point, in whatever language you prefer

Comment: @Aristos Why? I mean, I wait for the  login.aspx, login.asp and login.php answere and then I made the redirect.

Comment: @Steve can you please be more clear? I have all my user in one table for all the services. What do you mean saying ** go through one central point** ?

Comment: means one page - one validate code

Comment: I say to make a redirect to all pages, to move to one, transparently, before the login....

Comment: @Aristos I need to start the session after the authentication (if it's valid), so a redirect before the login it's unnecessary in my case.

Comment: for sure you do not understand what I suggest you - clear your mind for a bit. You do not need 3 pages - you only need one

Comment: Please, about the down-vote, I would like to receive a feedback/comment to understand why.

Comment: @Vixed, some things are a bit ouf of track. Editing the question to make it a bit more precise would help. Also giving output to people trying to help you would help. In this case, we're speaking about a problem without magic solutions. Apart from cookies, js-managed sessions (which are cookies in the end), a custom session provider and JWT, there's no other way out. So at this point probably everyone is waiting for your feedback (at least, i am) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like single sign-on to me. Let's try to split the problem.

> There is any way to check the login status through different programming language?

You're not really interested in the language used. Any language, given the same info and algorithm, would decode with success the same encrypted data. I guess you're instead having problems because PHP's application logic regarding this point is different from the ASP's one. 
So for the first point, you can

- Implement / normalize the same session checking logic among all of your apps. This is probably unfeasible, because you might be using Laravel here, and ASP.Net on the other, and the two are probably slightly different in this regard. If you can, do this, or...
- Look into JSON Web Tokens. I won't go into detail, but these were more or less designed to solve this class of problems. They are also easy to handle, but be aware, there are aspects you have to take care of when using them for user authentication.

> [...] Just to let you you know, I have to check the login session status before any ajax callback, so if the user is working on an ASP page calling PHP through Ajax, may be that the session is still active on the ASP, but expired on the php file.

Not to be that guy, but some concepts are somewhat deformed here. Sessions don't expire on files; they normally are setup with a given expiration time and a given *domain*. So generally speaking, a session opened from a PHP app, and stored on a cookie, then read from an ASP one shouldn't change, given that no difference exists between the two app's session handling logic.

> Any valid method to check all in one time? I can also accept a cookie solution but how to make it readable between php, asp and .net?

For both of the solutions i suggested above is, especially for the cookie one, it's important you make the apps absolutely identical in respect to session handling. While this is trivial with JWT (as there's barely any logic on the app's side), this may prove to be harder with cookies if the authentication logic comes from some one else's code (as in a framework).
I haven't asked about single sign-out, and at this point i'm afraid to ask :). But these are some guidelines:

- If going the cookie route, be aware of cookie's domain. A cookie is normally valid for every request coming from the website domain (name.com), but you may have some of your apps under a subdomain (like, phpapp.name.com). In this case, be sure the cookie created from the given app is valid for the *whole* domain, and not just the subdomain. And make the apps available at subdomains / pages under the same domain. Cookies don't work cross-domain, and you have to deal with that, since cookie domain policy is enforced at browser level.
- Launching three AJAX calls means triggering three login procedures. I suppose all of these would terminate, at some point in the future, and all of those would be storing / rewriting the cookie. If the apps understand the same cookie, it's mandatory you open the login process on *just one* of them. This would store the cookie, which would then be automatically picked app from, say, a page in the second app, giving you a seamless transition into a logged-state in the second app.
- JWT would normally require some JS work, which you may like since the same script can easily be loaded in all of your apps. On the other side, you can be sure that different server libraries handling JWT would all work the same for you, thus ensuring compatibility.

Personally, i would look into JSON Web Tokens.

Comment: Hi really like your answer, and I'll start to read something about JSON Web Tokens. The only problem seems to be that I'll have to setup nodeJS on IIS which is something I told to the company years ago... but.. you know o.O

Comment: @Vixed .. yes, i know -.-'
Happily away from IIS for some years now. Nonetheless, it looks like you can go without node.js? I know for sure there's [an extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205065(v=vs.110).aspx), or you can [implement it](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/) yourself (if we're speaking .NET)

Answer (score 3):

You can develop your own session provider which stores data in a separate place (for ex. in database or files). Then everything you need to do is write some code in every environment to handle your session information from that provider. Because you use only one source to store session information there will be no problem with synchronization between any of yours environment.

If you need then you can use a webservice for exchange session information between every environment and session provider. Every application can use security connection to get and set information about session from that session webservice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this!You can create provider which stores data into database. Then Write some cool code to manage your provider.You can also use webapp or sevice.Every service use security to get and put information.